# Android Textview settext issue in Samsung J5

Tags: java, android, eclipse, textview, settext

I have a "problem" with my application and I don't know what has happened.

I have this interface:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <Button
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:background="@color/white"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:textColor="@color/black" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/detailServiceTxtPhone"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:layout_marginTop="-35dp"
       android:ellipsize="end"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:maxLength="50"
       android:singleLine="true"
       android:textColor="@color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I get the field value from a web service and set text in java code:

```
m_txtPhone.setText(m_currentService.PassengerPhone);
```

In all the devices where I check it this is the result:
[image: 12345678]

But I have a problem in with Samsung J5 (5.1.1). When I try to set text in that `TextView` (and similars) I have this result:

[image: Empty view]

It seems that I have some problem setting the text or I don't know. Any idea?

NOTE:
I implement the interface in this way because in other cases I do something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/detailServiceBtnClient"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon_detail"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="@string/detailServiceBtnClient"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detailServiceTxtClient"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-35dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLength="50"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Cliente<--->aRTyMaNYa]

Comment: Why showing us the xml ? We need the code to understand "m_currentService.PassengerPhone"

Comment: Sorry. "m_currentService" is an object with all properties that defines a Service. That properties are phone, code, status, datetime creation, etc. I fill this properties with the web service response and i'm sure that these properties are filled but only in Samsung Galaxy J5 when I do the textview.setText the text is blank.

Comment: u sure these properties are filled. Please try a setText("Test") so

Comment: setText It's working in all my devices except in the Samsung Galaxy J5. I can try in Samsung Galaxy S4 & S5 &S6, BQ Aquaris E5, Samnsung Galaxy Tab 1 & 3 but is J5 the only one its not working jajaja. I'm doubting if is it the marginTop -35...

Answer (score 0):

You are using LinearLayout. In this layout items are added after each element. Your orientation is vertical, hence, it is below the button. Use RelativeLayout and then use alignTop and alignBottom properties of TextView.

```
android:alignTop="@+id/button"
android:alignBottom="@+id/button"
android:gravity="center"
```

Comment: Thanks Keshav. I tryied it and the result is the same, dont show any text... I modified the LinearLayout as a RelativeLayout and add layout_alignTop/Bottom in the textview xml code.

Comment: Remove marginTop in TextView

Comment: Its removed too.
If I put the textview before the button, appears the text but the text is bold and I dont put this style...